# How can I display an absolute flexbox item in the next line?

Tags: css, flexbox

I use the Wordpress CMS and show my articles like widgets. These widgets are wrapped using the class `main`, which has a `display:flex` attribute.

Before every widget starts, I have a div-container with the class flag being `position: absolute;`. This should display a flag beginning in the upper left corner of the widget.

But due to the fact the flag is set to absolute, the flag gets displayed at the end of the previous widget box, and does not show up in the next line.

http://jsfiddle.net/n2ft97nw/3/

Comment: You need to set a positioning context. The absolute 'flag' should have a parent with `position:relative`.

Comment: The flag shows correctly. It gets displayed above the widget. The only problem is, that the <div class="flag"> does not show up like the first "news" widget

Comment: Can't comment on code you haven't provided. A minimal example is required.

Comment: @Paulie_D I inserted a jsfiddle. the pink flags should be over the blue box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first comment was on the right path. There are a few things you need to do. Yes the flag needs to be positioned absolutely, but relative to what? The article that the flag belongs to. So here it is:

1. Put each flag inside the `<article>` div it belongs to.
2. Set the `<article>` to `position: relative;`
3. Position the flag by using CSS position properties:
   `top: 0;` and `left: -3px;` to offset for border on the article.

See the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n2ft97nw/7/

Comment: The flag should be on the widget box itself and not on the image

Comment: Thanks @OtakuKyon , my fiddle hadn't been updated to include the position rules. Fixed now. :)